# how to force simplification of power inequalities

Tags: simplifying-expressions

These two simple expressions fail to simplify (Mma 11.1):

```
FullSimplify[Power[x, n] < Power[y, n], Assumptions -> 0 < x < y && n >= 1]
FullSimplify[1 < Power[y/x, n], Assumptions -> 0 < x < y && n >= 1]
```

Logarithmic transformation helps; this works:

```
Simplify[Log /@ (Power[x, n] < Power[y, n]), Assumptions -> 0 < x < y && n >= 1]
```

Can I force simplification of the first two?

Comment: `FullSimplify[1 < Power[a, n], Assumptions -> a > 1 && n >= 1]` doesn't simplify either. No need for 3 variables.

Comment: Or even `FullSimplify[1 < Power[a, a], Assumptions -> a > 1]`.